# rootViewController instance method only works when app enters foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method on my rootViewController that disables horizontal scrolling within my app. When the user opens a search form within one page, I want the horizontal scrolling to be disabled. This is on the [search] page, like below:

[settings]-[*search*]-[people]-[chat]

The method is working properly, but only when I close out the app after first launch and reopen.

Here is the method on my rootViewController:

```
// .h
-(void)setScrollDisabled;

// .m
- (void)setScrollDisabled {
    _mainScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

I call it when the searchBar is active in my searchViewController:

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
...
    [self disableHorizontalScroll];
}


-(void)disableHorizontalScroll {
    TREAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TREAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[appDelegate rootViewController] setScrollDisabled];
}
```

I know that it does work, I just want it to work when the app launches in addition to when it enters the foreground. How do I make sure the same result is achieved in all cases?

Comment: I suspect you have some app settings that make all these problems. Google for app settigns related to the back/fore ground

Comment: I would think that was the case if the problem happened only after the app entered the foreground

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed a notification such as the following in my viewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TRESearchControllerOpenedNotification object:nil userInfo:@{TRESearchControllerSearchIsActive : @(YES)}];
```

and then in my rootViewController:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:TREActivityControllerOpenedNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

```
if ([note userInfo][TRESearchControllerSearchIsActive]) {
    BOOL searchIsActive = [[note userInfo][TRESearchControllerSearchIsActive] boolValue];
    if (searchIsActive) {
        [self setScrollDisabled];
    }
}

}];
```

along with the proper declarations...